# Sets: How to show that relation R is not transitive?

Tags: relations

I have a question which states:

> $R = \{ (t,t), (t,v), (t,z), (u,t), (u,u), (u,v), (u,x), (u,z), (v,v), (w,w), (w,z), (x,t), (x,v), (x,w), (x,x), (x,y), (x,z), (y,w), (y,y), (y,z), (z,z) \}$
>
> "Give a counter example to show $R$ is not transitive ... "

I understand that $R$ is said to be transitive if $(a,b) \in R$  and $(b,c) \in R$, implies $(a,c) \in R$. If these conditions aren't met then the relation is not transitive.

How could apply this in the example? Thank you.

Comment: Please circumvent to pay thanks for every answer but just vote them up, if they are of any help.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately can't yet as I am a new user.

Comment: Why you can't upvote? I really apprehend. :)

Comment: It doesn't let you unless you have 15+ reputation.

Comment: But you should accept one of them. It doesn't require any charges :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $R$ is small, you can actually consider all possibilities for $a,b$, and $c$. However, this is easier if you have a systematic arrangement of the ordered pairs. One way is to represent them by a matrix:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
&t&u&v&w&x&y&z\\ \hline
t&1&&1&&&&1\\
u&1&1&1&&1&&1\\
v&&&1\\
w&&&&1&&&1\\
x&1&&1&1&1&1&1\\
y&&&&1&&1&1\\
z&&&&&&&1
\end{array}$$

Here there is a $1$ in row $t$, column $v$, for instance, because the pair $\langle t,v\rangle$ is in $R$. Each of the other $1$s represents one of the other ordered pairs in $R$. Now you want to find $a,b,c\in\{t,u,v,w,x,y,z\}$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle b,c\rangle$ are in $R$, but $\langle a,c\rangle$ is not in $R$.

Notice that $x$ is related by $R$ to almost everything – everything except $u$, in fact – so it’s easy to find pairs $\langle x,\star\rangle\in R$. The only pair with first element $x$ that is *not* in $R$ is $\langle x,u\rangle$; can you find a $\star$ such that $\langle x,\star\rangle$ and $\langle\star,u\rangle$ are in $R$?

**Added:** That attempt fails, because the $u$ column has only $u$ in it, so we might try for $\langle u,\star\rangle$ and $\langle\star,w\rangle$, or $\langle u,\star\rangle$ and $\langle\star,y\rangle$; this time it turns out that both yield counterexamples.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian. I will definitely use this method in the future.

Comment: @user95665: You're very welcome.

Comment: No, you can't. Probably a bad choice of example?

Comment: @immibis: No, forgetting to come back and complete the answer after I was called away for a bit. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. You need to find three specific elements (we'll call them $a$, $b$, and $c$) such that $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ belong to $R$, but $(a,c)$ does not. Here's a hint: suppose $u$ is our $a$, and $x$ is our $b$. $(u,x$) belongs to $R$. Now see if there is some $c$ such that $(x,c)$ belongs to $R$, but $(u,c)$ doesn't.

Comment: Is the answer R = {u,x) R = {x, w} -> R =/ {u,w} ?

Comment: Yes! $(u,x) \in R$ and $(x,w) \in R$, but $(u,w) \not\in R$.

Comment: Thank you very much Ken!. You are very good at explaining things.

Comment: You're welcome! And, thank you. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the set you are provided. If relation on the set is transitive then it must satisfy the condition i.e. if $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ then $(a,c)$ does $\forall a,b,c \in S$

You can use definition to prove or disprove a statement given for a Relation. Nothing changes in your reasoning but the elements.

Well, it may take enough time to check whether your set is transitive or not. But you have to do it. :)

Comment: I can help more if you want :)

Comment: I'm sure I will need more lol. It is very much appreciated.